# Journal name missing if paper is cited again in another refsection (biblatex chicago)

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

EDIT: We have found this is an issue specific to Overleaf.

I have multiple `refsection`s and multiple bibliographies in my document. When I cite the same paper in a different `refsection` the journal name is missing in the reference list.

In the MWE below the bibliography in the Introduction would be correct. In the Discussion I would see the full reference to Jones, but the Journal of the Smith paper is missing.

I have tried `noibid` and the `ibidtracker=false` option but to no avail. I think I need some sort of option to completely clear the memory between chapters. Changing the citekey for duplicate papers solves this issue but I would prefer  not having to do that.

This is the updated version of the MWE that replicates the described problem

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib, authordate,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,    ibidtracker=false,noibid]{biblatex-chicago}    
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Introduction.bib}
@article{Spruijt2006b,
title = {{Advanced behavioural screening: automated home cage ethology}},
year = {2006},
journal = {Drug Discovery Today: Technologies},
author = {Spruijt, Berry M. and DeVisser, Leonie},
number = {2},
month = {6},
pages = {231--237},
volume = {3},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1740674906000345},
doi = {10.1016/j.ddtec.2006.06.010},
issn = {17406749},
pmid = {24980412}
}
@article{Gerlai2002a,
title = {{Phenomics: fiction or the future?}},
year = {2002},
journal = {Trends in Neurosciences},
author = {Gerlai, Robert},
number = {10},
month = {10},
pages = {506--509},
volume = {25},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0166223602022506},
doi = {10.1016/S0166-2236(02)02250-6},
issn = {01662236},
pmid = {12220878}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Discussion.bib}
@article{Spruijt2006b,
title = {{Advanced behavioural screening: automated home cage ethology}},
year = {2006},
journal = {Drug Discovery Today: Technologies},
author = {Spruijt, Berry M. and DeVisser, Leonie},
number = {2},
month = {6},
pages = {231--237},
volume = {3},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1740674906000345},
doi = {10.1016/j.ddtec.2006.06.010},
issn = {17406749},
pmid = {24980412}
}
@article{Gerlai2002a,
title = {{Phenomics: fiction or the future?}},
year = {2002},
journal = {Trends in Neurosciences},
author = {Gerlai, Robert},
number = {10},
month = {10},
pages = {506--509},
volume = {25},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0166223602022506},
doi = {10.1016/S0166-2236(02)02250-6},
issn = {01662236},
pmid = {12220878}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Introduction.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[Introduction.bib]  
\chapter[General Introduction]{General Introduction}
this is a sentence
\citep{Spruijt2006b}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

\chapter[General Discussion]{General Discussion}
\begin{refsection}[Discussion.bib]
\citep{Spruijt2006b}
\citep{Gerlai2002a}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

The results for the second chapter are

```
Chapter 2
General Discussion
(Spruijt and DeVisser 2006) (Gerlai 2002)
References
Gerlai, Robert. 2002. “Phenomics: fiction or the future?” Trends in             Neurosciences
25, no. 10 (October): 506–509.
Spruijt, Berry M., and Leonie DeVisser. 2006. “Advanced behavioural screening:
automated home cage ethology.” 3, no. 2 (June): 231–237.
```

Comment: There are a few mistakes in your MWE. Maybe you can make it compilable. `Smith2009` is missing in your examples. Please make sure that the MWE compiles and shows the error.

Comment: There are no journal articles in your bibliographies, only books

Comment: Since `refsection`s are kept entirely separate from each other on a Biber level and also for `biblatex` internals, the two should not influence each other. So I would be really interested in seeing an MWE that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I'm working on it. My apologies for my sloppiness. Finishing a thesis and the stress is getting to me... Sorry.

Comment: I cleaned up your code and made it run and everything works just fine. So, the error might lie elsewhere

Comment: I posted the code as an answer, maybe it helps you find your error. Btw. have you cleaned up old aux files and the like?

Comment: I edited the MWE to reproduce the problem

Comment: Your new MWE misses `Discussion.bib`.

Comment: If I simply copy the contents of `Introduction.bib` to `Discussion.bib` things look OK. Are you sure that `Discussion.bib` contains the entries exactly as in `Introduction.bib`?

Comment: I added Discusison.bib. It doesn't solve the problem.
I use overleaf by the way. The MWE is here https://www.overleaf.com/13647016kxhfkndfjwzx#/52772744/

Comment: OK the MWE works for me on my local install with `biblatex` 3.10/Biber 2.10. The fact that it does not work on Overleaf makes me think it is caused by a bug in Biber that was fixed in the meantime. I don't think there is a lot you can do about this.

Comment: I pasted DG's code into Overleaf and it shows the same problem indeed. So we can confirm this is an Overleaf situation. FML, now I have to manually adjust all these references.... Thanks for the help and the patience.

Comment: Good to know (although bad for you). I will remove my "answer" then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE works for me with `biblatex` 3.10/Biber 2.10. On Overleaf I can indeed reproduce the problem (https://www.overleaf.com/read/zdnpmspxkkyr, a simpler MWE would be https://www.overleaf.com/read/sdgcvxmnvjhw), this seems to be a Biber bug that was fixed a while ago.

The work-around is to use `journaltitle` instead of `journal`

```
@article{Spruijt2006b,
  title = {{Advanced behavioural screening: automated home cage ethology}},
  year = {2006},
  journaltitle = {Drug Discovery Today: Technologies},
  author = {Spruijt, Berry M. and DeVisser, Leonie},
  number = {2},
  month = {6},
  pages = {231--237},
  volume = {3},
  url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1740674906000345},
  doi = {10.1016/j.ddtec.2006.06.010},
  issn = {17406749},
  pmid = {24980412}
}
```

See https://www.overleaf.com/read/zzrfttnshsdc

So the problem seems to be that Biber failed to execute certain source mapping steps for `.bib` files other than the first file loaded.

Comment: How do  you mean "use journaltitle"?

Comment: @Nightingale Write `journaltitle = {Drug Discovery Today: Technologies},` instead of `journal = {Drug Discovery Today: Technologies},`

Comment: Ah okay, so I will still need to edit all my references. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Nightingale But that is not too bad. If you have an editor that does search and replace, search for `journal = ` and replace by `journaltitle = ` and you are done.

Comment: @Nightingale Do you use Overleaf to write your actual paper? If so, you can use the 'replace' function that you can access via 'Find' in the top bar. Simply replace `journal = ` with `journaltitle = ` and everything will work fine.

Comment: I use a linked Mendeley bibliography> Which is great because it is updated automatically, but not so great in this situation because I cannot find and replace. I send a message to the people at Overleaf. THey might be able to fix it...